Omitting a degree on my ds160
I completed my Masters in engineering from USA last year. I have 2 Bachelors in my home country (1 in engineering and 1 in an unrelated field) and during my second in the unrelated field I was working as an engineer as well. I did not specify my second bachelors on the ds160 as at that time I thought it wasn’t relevant.
I am back in my home country after my Masters and planning to do a PhD. While filing the ds160, I was told by a friend that not specifying my 2nd bachelors in the first ds160 is misrepresentation and will result in a lifetime ban. Is this right? What can I do now?

Why do you think the question is urgent?

Have you received the visa?  Have you been to the interview?  Can you amend your DS-160 or submit a new one?
